# Why don't I get a PHP notice that the array index does not exist if I put an isset() in the same IF-statement?

Tags: php, isset, comparison-operators, short-circuiting

Situation: We have a small piece of PHP code which checks if a variable has a certain value, but since the array index and it's value haven't been set at all, this will create an E_NOTICE error:

### This triggers a notice

```
<?php

    $arr = array();

    if ($arr['name']=='john') {
        echo('This should not work');
    } else {
        echo('In your computer, ignoring your notice');
    }
```

This throws a nice notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/hvanmegen/test.php on line 5
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/hvanmegen/test.php:0
```

Now please explain to me, if that value check throws an error, HOW does the code printed below work just fine without throwing that same exception?!?!

### This doesn't triggers a notice!

```
<?php

    $arr = array();

    if (isset($arr['name']) && $arr['name']=='john') {
        echo('This should not work');
    } else {
        echo('In your computer, ignoring your notice');
    }
```

Output:

```
In your computer, ignoring your notice
```

### Are AND-checks just aborted/thrown out as soon as the first false gets returned or something?

Does PHP just skip the second check and never actually perform the second check whenever the first false is triggered in a list of comparisons??

Also, is it considered good coding practise to separate the two if statements or am I being a bit too old fashioned with my coding here? One would think that the correct way to check this would be this:

```
<?php

    $arr = array();

    if (isset($arr['name'])) {
        if ($arr['name']=='john') {
            echo('Hi john');
        } else {
            echo('Hi not-john, where is john?');
        }
    } else {
        echo('I cannot check what I do not have');
    }
```

Output:

```
I cannot check what I do not have
```

Is it just my OCD that wants to put the 'isset()' outside the other statement or is my  approach totally superfluous and outdated? Or am I clinging to the idea that you should write code in as much 'common tongue' (use language independent syntax, to make switching from one language to the next as easy as possible) as you can?

How do other programming and scripting languages (Java, C++/C#, Javascript, Python) handle this?

Comment: empty arrays dont have any indexes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does PHP just skip the second check and never actually perform the second check whenever the first false is triggered in a list of comparisons??

Yes. It's called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

`&&` (and) doesn't evaluate the right-hand side if the left-hand side is false, since the result *must* be false.

`||` (or) doesn't evaluate the right-hand side if the left-hand side is true, since the result *must* be true.

> Also, is it considered good coding practice to separate the two if statements or am I being a bit too old fashioned with my coding here?

Although coding style is very personal, it's not necessary to separate them once you understand short-circuit evaluation. I believe most programmers would keep the conditions in one `if` in this case, particularly since they are closely related and are basically two steps towards checking the same thing.

> How do other programming and scripting languages (Java, C++/C#, JavaScript, Python) handle this?

The same as PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. you made this a lot clearer for me, hopefully this will help someone in the future as well :)

Comment: This is a good answer about short-circuiting.  Additionally, it's important to point out the "implied" fact that `isset()` is a "language construct" that, unlike regular functions, will never generate `E_NOTICE`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isset($arr['name']) && $arr['name']=='john')
```

Yes for sure with `&&` operator if the first condition is false compiler or interpreter will not waste time in checking other conditions as it is useless. So in this case second condition is not evaluated.

Again `if (isset($arr['name'])) {` this condition is false so it will jump to else.

```
echo('I cannot check what I do not have');
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP isset is not a function.
It's a builtin, and I suspect it does some language level magic. That's why you don't get the warning in the second case.

I normally write a helper function like so to deal with this:

```
function check($array, $key, $expected) {
    if (!isset($array[$key]) return false;
    return $array[$key] == $expected;
}
```

> Does PHP just skip the second check and never actually perform 
>     the second check whenever the first false is triggered in a list of comparisons??

Yes, boolean operators in PHP perform [short-curcuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation): the sub-expressions are evaluated left to right, and once the interpreter knows enough, it returns without evalueating the remaining sub-expressions.

> How do other programming and scripting 
>     languages (Java, C++/C#, Javascript, Python) handle this?

C++ handles it by default constructing the value_type (Effectivly, returns a new empty string that gets inserted into that index of the map.) and has other methods for access without modification.

Ruby returns null or the default values specified in the constructor.

PHP is a bit annoying with silently failing in some places, and giving warnings in other places where not expected.

If I didn't care about the non-existent key I'd write: 
    if (check($arr, 'name', john')) {
        echo('Hi John');
    } else {
        echo('I don\'t know who you are.');
    }

Comment: How is this an answer to the OP's question?

Comment: It's not a function at all. It's a language construct

Comment: @nl-x Thats what I meant by builtin

Comment: @daan I think it answers the questions now.

Comment: @nishantjr I think his addition of the check() function was useful, thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
  if ($arr['name']=='john') { ...
```

if you don't have an array element with the key 'name' it renders an error.

```
  isset($arr['name'])
```

on the other hand just checks whether there is an element with the key 'name'.
it just loops through the array of keys (pretty fast on an empty array) and return true key exists.

Conclusion: if you access an array element $arr['name'] you should be sur that there is such an element. if you are not sure check first for the existance with isset($arr['name'])

Hope it helps!

Comment: "it just loops through the array of keys" No it doesn't. It's a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). This doesn't answer the question by the way.